# Noob Python While Loop

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will ask a user to enter a number and then ask them if they want to enter another number.  Based on the numbers they enter the program will sum them and give the average of them.

Here is what I have so far but I understand it doesnt work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
more = input("Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: ")

def funct(more):
    while more == "Y":
        b = int(input("Enter another number: "))
        abSum = a + b
        abMean = a + b / 2
        if more == "Y":
            return b
        else:
            break

    print(abSum)
    print(abMean)
```

Comment: Your code has a function definition in it, but you're not calling that function anywhere. Do you need a function to handle what you're trying to do, or is that something you're not sure about?

Comment: Your right, I completely forgot it.  Working on it while calling it atm

Comment: Your calculation for `abMean` is incorrect.  Consider the inputs 2, 2, 2, 10.  Your code would give `6` while `4` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
more = input("Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: ")
summ=a          #intialize sum to a
count=1         # no. of integers entered, to calculate mean
while more.lower()=="y":
    b = int(input("Enter another number: "))
    count+=1          #increase count by 1
    summ+= b          #add b to sum
    abMean = summ/float(count)         #used float(count) to get actual value

    print("sum=",summ)
    print("mean=",abMean)    
    more = input("Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: ") #ask for user input
print("sum=",summ)
print("mean=",abMean)
```

**output:**

```
Enter a number: 5
Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: y
Enter another number: 5
sum= 10
mean= 5.0
Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: y
Enter another number: 2
sum= 12
mean= 4.0
Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: y
Enter another number: 15
sum= 27
mean= 6.75
Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: y
Enter another number: 10
sum= 37
mean= 7.4
Please enter Y or N if you want to add more numbers: n
sum= 37
mean= 7.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplified, your program could look like this:

```
abSum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

while raw_input("Please enter Y if you want to add more numbers or anything else to finish: ") == 'Y':
    b = int(raw_input("Enter another number: "))
    abSum = abSum + b
    abMean = abSum / 2

print(abSum)
print(abMean)
```

Basically you loop until user enters and empty line, or anything else in the second prompt, and then fix your sums/means.

You don't necessarily need a separate function for the task you're trying to accomplish. If you want a function for, say, a homework - then you can rewrite the piece to pass the value of `b` to a separate function that will update the `abSum` and `abMean` and call that from within the `while` loop.

Umm, and pardon me, my example doesn't actually calculate a mean, you need to count the number of entered values into, for instance, a third variable and then divide by that amount. Another answerer proposed a solution with a list of entered values that could work in your case.

Comment: This is really helpful, however I am trying to make it so it will keep asking you if you want to add more numbers and then will sum and mean the numbers you have entered.  This could be 1 or 20 numbers

Comment: See edit, and proposed solution of @girasquid for the real mean calculation.

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned this up and turned it into a self contained script for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def ask_for_some_numbers():
    numbers = []
    more = 'y'
    while more.lower() == 'y':
        number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
        numbers.append(number)
        more = raw_input("Please enter Y if you want to add more numbers: ")
    print (sum(numbers))
    print (sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ask_for_some_numbers()
```

Here's what's different:

- I use a list to store the numbers (`numbers = []`) - that way you can easily have an arbitrarily large amounth of numbers.
- I call the function to start prompting for numbers.
- I use `raw_input` instead of `input`. The [documentation for input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) recommends using raw_input for input from your users, because `input` will evaluate what gets entered (this could cause you problems if you have a malicious user).
- I use the built-in `sum` method to sum up the items in the list.

Comment: I guessed, from the use of `int(input())` and `print()` that the questioner is using Python3. I suppose that's not certain though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's simple bit of code to loop that will ask for numbers until it gets a blank entry, after which it will print the sum and average of the inputs:

```
total = 0
count = 0

num = input("Enter a number: ")

while (num):
    total += int(num)
    count += 1
    num = input("Enter another number (or a blank line to quit): ")

print("Total =", total)
print("Average =", total/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you need to call the function somewhere?

something like (untested):

```
if a and more=="Y":
    funct(more)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: anyways...by calling the function he solves his problem...see above in the comment...